# ESXi 6 Free Limits / Restrictions

Tags: vmware-esxi

I've played with ESXi on a local server and wanted to know with the free version could I create VM (CentOS), install WordPress on the VM and host a few websites for my customers (each customer having their own VM)?  Maybe around 50 or so? Of course I would move the server to a local datacenter and get the necessary IP's for each machine from them.  My question is more about the limits or restrictions to ESXi. And I'm guessing I can use vSphere to manage the server.
Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: This is a case where you should just look at the VMware ESXi product page.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the useful features like moving VMs between hosts etc dont work, the API is read-only not write and no HA. I think you have a RAM limit per host (64gb I believe), possibly no core limit but a limit of 2 physical CPU's and using the vsphere client (not full fat) you can only manage one host at a time. You cant use vcenter

I believe TOS allows you to run production services though

You could run all customers on the same or a few VMs with each having a host entry using something like Apache mod-proxy. Would save on a heap of resources Or you could just have each site bound to a different IP but still on the same VM

Comment: `I think you have a RAM limit`? Do you have any documentation or links to back up that claim?

Comment: My intent is to run VERY simple wordpress sites, each site having maybe 10 pages or so.  The server has only 48GB of memory and I was planning on giving each VM maybe 4GB.  Even if the limit with ESXi is 64GB per host, I'm good with that, unless running a VM with only 4GB is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: 50 x 4GB = 200GB. Even with page sharing and all the fun stuff that ESXi does, that's a 4:1 overcommitment of RAM, which is fairly high. Never mind the overhead of each VM, the hypervisor itself and Disk & CPU contention, that sounds little bit like a bad idea.